# Python Pandas: How to retrieve row index of multiple values

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to get the row index of the row that contains certain values(more than one).

I have tried put the values that I would like to retrieve in a list but failed, I can only search the index one by one which is quite tedious.

Possible but tedious

```
rows.loc[rows['NO']=='NO'].index.values
rows.loc[rows['NO']=='Sub Total :'].index.values
rows.loc[rows['NO']=='Generated By:'].index.values
rows.loc[rows['NO']=='Product :'].index.values
```

Failed

```
rows.loc[rows['NO']==list1].index.values
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
rows.loc[rows['NO'].isin(list1)].index.values
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) as:

```
l = ['NO','Sub Total :', 'Generated By:', 'Product :']
index = rows.loc[rows['NO'].str.contains('|'.join(l)), 'NO'].index.values
```